# How to make element of LinearLayout not fill all possible space with weight=1 width=0

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have next layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/work_item_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textSize="6sp"
                android:id="@+id/work_item_update"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="LALALALLALLALALALALALALLA...."
                android:id="@+id/work_item_title">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:id="@+id/work_item_rate_and_size"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Problem is central TextView fill all available space but i want it to be minimum possible space. If i make width of central TextView "warp_content" then last one will be erased if central would big enough to fill all space. 
How should i make central element width be like warp_content but last one must not be erased if central text is more then 1 line (i want that last one TextView text will be right next to central TextView text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using weights exactly backwards.  Try assigning `android:weight="1"` for the top and bottom `TextView`s and specifying only "wrap_content" for the middle one.

Alternatively, you could specify large weights (4 or 5) to each of the outside views and a smaller weight (1) for the inside one.

Weight takes precedence.  If you specify a weight for a view, the `LinearLayout` will use it, in preference to other size specifications, to size the view.  If you specify both weight and some other size, the `LinearLayout` size computation is excessively expensive.  That is why you will see a recommendation, in your IDE, telling you to explicitly set the size to "0", if you specify a weight.

Specifying a non-zero weight *can* be useful.  While weight takes precedence if there is space to spare, the `LinearLayout` size calculation algorithm will not make a view smaller that its specified size.  That means that you can say, more or less "give this view 1/3rd of the screen, or 12 pixels, whichever is larger"

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning weights that way you can specify the fraction of space you want your view to occupy